# Advanced Installer UI events

Tags: advanced-installer

I'm using Advanced Installer 14.2 and need to detect when a scroll box is scrolled to the bottom. If true, then set the "enable" property for the "Next" button. I don't see a scroll box attribute I can use to detect the scrolled to the bottom state. My requirement is to force the user to scroll through the entire EULA before being able to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for this in the FAQ from the from [advancedinstaller.com](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/faq-ui.html#question144).